# Chi-squared Test in R (to compare real data to theoretical normal distribution)

Tags: r, chi-squared

I’d like to make a Chi-squared Test to compare my data (column “real”) with the theoretical normal distribution (column “theor”), that was calculated (in Excel) by the parameters of the big real sample (processing of this sample to ranks - is the column “real”).

What test in R I should use for this purpose?

At first I thought that it should be `chisq.test`

But I compare its result to the result of the function “CHI2TEST” in EXCEL (that should give the same result) and these results were quite different. It gives p-value = 0.2426, and CHI2TEST of Excel gives p-value 0.87.

Maybe I used `chisq.test` incorrectly? Could you check my script or advise me correct test for Chi-squared Test in R?

```
> real
[1]  2  3 15 22 21 14  2  1
> theor
[1]  1.4  5.7 14.1 21.6 20.2 11.6  4.1  0.9
> chisq.test (real,theor)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  real and theor
X-squared = 48, df = 42, p-value = 0.2426  

Warning message:
In chisq.test(real, theor) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Comment: Do you mean the `CHITEST` in Excel? I can't find a `CHI2TEST`...

Comment: @CephBirk: Try looking in EXCEL for `CHISQ.TEST`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`chisq.test` is for contingency tables and that is not what you are giving it. (Notice the degrees of freedom is 42, so it thinks your "real" variables are counts rather than numeric measurements. Take a look at this implementation of a Pearson chi-squared test:

```
> chisq <- sum( (real-theor)^2/theor)

> chisq
[1] 3.2159
> pchisq(chisq, length(theor)-1 )   # df = n-1
[1] 0.1356627                          
> 1- pchisq(chisq, length(theor)-1 )
[1] 0.8643373       
             # compare to Excel
```

There are many different versions of "chi-squared" tests. So many in fact that anyone who only describes their analysis as "using a chi-squared test" should be suspected of incompetence. This test above might be described as chi-squared test of goodness of fit of measured to theoretical.

Comment: Very informative, thank you. The help page for `chisq.test` says "chisq.test performs chi-squared contingency table tests and goodness-of-fit tests." Is it possible to use the function for a goodness of fit test as well rather than the manual calculation as you have done?

Comment: I didn't see a method of doing so. BTW, this is not what you described. It's not a test of Normality.